# How to create running timeline on the fly? - SQL

Tags: sql, database, google-bigquery, window-functions, recursive-query

I want to create a dataset that captures a running timeline of events based on `avg_time` and `num_events`. The idea is to start at `00:00:00.00000` and create a timeline by adding `avg_time` in milliseconds to the previous time for `num_events` number of times.

Sample Data:

```
id    avg_time   num_events
1     43         3
2     23         2
3     59         1
```

Desired Output:

```
id    start_time         end_time
1     00:00:00.00000     00:00:00.04300
1     00:00:00.04300     00:00:00.08600
1     00:00:00.08600     00:00:00.12900
2     00:00:00.00000     00:00:00.02300
2     00:00:00.02300     00:00:00.04600
3     00:00:00.00000     00:00:00.05900
```

Honestly can't wrap my head around how I can do this. Maybe need to use while loops or recursive queries but is there a simpler way? Not sure if window functions are even applicable.

My attempt:

```
SELECT 
   id
 , CASE WHEN -- logic to identify first event
    THEN CAST('00:00:00.00000') AS start_time
   ELSE -- LAG() to capture previous row end_time somehow?
   END AS start_time
 , TIME_ADD(--prev_start_time, INTERVAL avg_time MILLISECOND)
FROM my_table
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below query:

```sql
with sample_data as (
  select 1 as id, 43 as avg_time, 3 as num_events, 
  union all select 2 as id, 23 as avg_time, 2 as num_events,
  union all select 3 as id, 59 as avg_time, 1 as num_events
),
t1 as (
select 
  *,
  sum(avg_time) over (partition by id order by avg_time ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as end_time,
from sample_data, 
unnest(generate_array(1,num_events)) as arr 
)

select 
  id,
  avg_time,
  time_add(time(0, 0, 0),interval lag(end_time) over (partition by id order by avg_time) millisecond) as start_time,
  time_add(time(0, 0, 0), interval end_time millisecond) as end_time
from t1
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Because of `LAG(end_time)`, I'm guessing this may not work with decimal  values. Is there an easy workaround for this?

Comment: @RicardoFrancois what do you mean by working with decimal values? Can you provide an example?